# Select parent link

Tags: jquery

Having attached a click event to html for clicking on a link, I place the clicked link in a variable, to be able to assign a css rule to it later:

```
$("html").on('click', '.someclass a', function(event) {

var clickedlink = $(this);

// a long chain of conditionals and functions

$(clickedlink).css("color", "red"):

}
```

I want to be able to also select a parent link (ul a) if the clicked link is in a submenu (ul ul a), so that I can assign the same css rule to the parent link.

I tried

```
var clickedlinkparent = $(this).parent();

$(clickedlinkparent).css("color", "red");
```

But this results in nothing, so I'm doing something wrong. What's the proper way to do that?

**UPDATE:** here's the structure of the menu, aas you can see, the most basic one:

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <ul id="menu" class="nav-menu">
       <li>
          <a href="http://www.someurl.com/">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>ABOUT</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="http://www.someotherurl.com/">Our Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.yetsomeotherurl.com/">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.someevenlongerurl.com/">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

So, what I want is, when Our Company link is clicked, both Our Company and ABOUT to have the same CSS assigned to them.

Comment: Can we see the HTML? Also, there's no need to do `$(clickedlink)` - `clickedlink` is already a jQuery object, wrapping it again is pointless.

Comment: Can you put your HTML code

Comment: For maximum useless jQuery wrapping you should have been using this: `var clickedlink = $($(this));`. Ahhh! now it's cool jQuery code.

Comment: @gdoron i think OP is a newbie in jquery, don't you think? Anyway your comment is funny

Comment: @roasted, I think so too, but if we won't comment how will he learn(and we laugh a bit...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

[http://jsfiddle.net/fXxev/4](http://jsfiddle.net/fXxev/4/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub-menu a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $clickedlink = $(this);

    // a long chain of conditionals and functions

    $clickedlink.add($clickedlink.parents('li').find('> a')).css("color", "red");

});
```

Comment: Hi @roasted. I like your solution, but it disables my AJAX. ;-)

Comment: There must be a different typo in the updated code, @roasted, because it disables my AJAX in a different way now... even though I can't help feeling that your solution is on the right track...

Comment: Is there a more basic way to get to the same element, @roasted? Sort of like "go up the dome... a little more up... select `a`"?

Comment: trying with prevent default now, @roasted

Comment: I admit I didn't read the question and not even your answer, but it's beginning is bad. `$(document).on('click'...` don't attach to `document` events.

Comment: trying parents('a').first.

Comment: @gdoron and you think its better to attach to 'html'? OP wants to use delegation, maybe there is good reason, maybe not, i don't know. What is the closest static container? If you know, just let me know ;)

Comment: `var clickedlinkparent = $(this).parents('a').first();` does NOT break AJAX (already a great news) but does NOT select the parent link, either ;-(

Comment: because i suspect you don't have parent link, you have a parent which contains a link? Is it? You should update your question with relevant html code. BTW, there is absolutely no reason .closest() would break any ajax request. Check your console, you should see what you done wrong

Comment: Updated the question, @roasted, to include the structure of the nav menu. The entire code would take A LOT more space, so I had to boil it down a bit.

Comment: Tested the updated answer, @roasted. Nope, disables the AJAX.

Comment: There's a preventDefault already in my code, @roasted. For some reason, if I put `var $clickedlink = $(this);` after `preventDefault`, AJAX is disabled. If I put it before, the parent doesn't get selected.

Comment: I appreciate your effort in this, @roasted. It seems like it should be the correct solution, but there's something there that somehow disables my script. Should I post the entire script in the question?

Comment: I cannot see how you are using AJAX request?! Any error in your console? If yes, post it. BTW, post your ajax code too. Still BTW, are you sure what you call AJAX is actually AJAX?

Comment: Posted the whole AJAX script in the question. @roasted. The commented out link selection does not disable the code, but selects only the clicked link, not that link and the parent.

Comment: $("html")  firstly attach to document, not 'html'  $(document) and not $('document')  Then, your code is quite unreadable, use your console, maybe there is some errors.  BTW, it is $clickedlink not clickedlink ($). Seriously, debug your code using console!

Comment: Let me try all that you suggested, @roasted. Sorry about the unreadability.

Comment: GUESS WHAT, @roasted?! Here's what made it work: `$(clickedlink).add($(clickedlink).parents('li').find('> a')).css("color", "red");` WHY, though?! It's redundant, correct? Why doesn't it work without ()?

Comment: if var clickedlink = $(this); you don't need to wrap it again in a jquery object. In your case: clickedlink.add(clickedlink.parents()... would work too. In MY ANSWER, i use var $clickedlink = $(this) because its common convention to prefix jq var with ($). So in this case you have to use: $clickedlink.add($clickedlink.parents()...  You, you rewrap an already jquery object inside a jquery object, it's useless even it works. You should read more carefully answer next time and see exactly what is not the same and adapt your code and not just copy/paste code. Hope you understood

Comment: Ah! I got it!!! Thank you, @roasted, I should have read your answer more carefully. Thanks for helping to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Note: Once you've saved the element in clickedLink, you do not need to put it inside of the jquery finder again.

```
clickedlink.css("color", "red");

clickedlinkparent.css("color", "red");
```

Also useful, if you're not sure if you're selecting the right element, you can always use console.log().

```
console.log(clickedLink);
```

Comment: That's is not an answer, though it's true and I commented about it as well.